# How to update data in back process django

Tags: python, django, web, automation

I have a website in Django who collects data from several logs and create and manipulates objects accordingly. This far I have used django commands to run the parsers and do this actions.
I am wondering if this is the correct way to do such action? Please share your thought with me thank you!

Comment: use django-celery or django-cron for repeted tasks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cron utility in Linux to run your commands in specified time.

Also, you can use a task queue like [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/) in your project.